# Docker MinIO entrypoint

Tags: windows, macos, docker, minio

I have this project which was initially set up on Mac, I'm on Windows, it's a Docker project which runs Node, Kafka and a few other containers, one of them being MinIO. Everything works as intended except MinIO, I get the following error:

```
createbuckets_1  | /bin/sh: nc: command not found
```

Docker-compose code:

```
  createbuckets:
    image: minio/mc
    networks:
      - localnet
    depends_on:
      - minio
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c "
      while ! nc -zv minio 9000; do echo 'Wait minio to startup...' && sleep 0.1; done; sleep 5;
      /usr/bin/mc config host add myminio http://minio:9000 X X;
      /usr/bin/mc rm -r --force myminio/cronify/details;
      /usr/bin/mc mb myminio/cronify/details;
      /usr/bin/mc policy set download myminio/cronify/details;
      exit 0;"
```

Where X is, credentials are supposed to be.
I have been trying to find a fix for weeks.

I have also tried to change the entrypoint from `/bin/sh -c` to `/bin/bash -c` or `#!/bin/bash -c` or `#!/bin/sh -c`, I get the same error except `".../bin/bash: nc: command not found"`.

Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar issue, but I am running minio on docker containers only (no docker-compose). However the code looks similar and I think this should work. You have to change only one line in your docker-compose file. This `nc -zv minio 9000` should be replaced with `curl -I http://minio:9000/minio/health/live`.

Below is the entire snipped:

```
  createbuckets:
    image: minio/mc
    networks:
      - localnet
    depends_on:
      - minio
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c "
      while ! curl -I http://minio:9000/minio/health/live; do echo 'Wait minio to startup...' && sleep 0.1; done; sleep 5;
      /usr/bin/mc config host add myminio http://minio:9000 X X;
      /usr/bin/mc rm -r --force myminio/cronify/details;
      /usr/bin/mc mb myminio/cronify/details;
      /usr/bin/mc policy set download myminio/cronify/details;
      exit 0;"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking here, but if you are asking about the error message itself, it is telling you that `nc` is not installed (because it won't be in a container).  I am also not clear on which container minio is running in.  Assuming the container is being pulled from minio/minio, then it will have curl installed, and you can just use the health check endpoint instead of trying to use nc - https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/monitoring/healthcheck-probe.html#minio-healthcheck-api.  If it is not a minio container, you would just need to make sure it has curl installed (or `nc` if for some reason you were set on using that).

Comment: Thanks for the info, you actually managed to head me on the right path. Although I still didn't manage to solve it, but at least I got a better idea of what the issue might be.

I will edit my post with the full container code from docker-compose.